# Custom Authentication Web Service

Tags: liferay

I want to use authentication web services that is exposed by my legacy client. But I cannot copy those user information in to liferay database. Can any one help me to write a custom authentication service OR a hook/plugin to reuse my own implementation for authentication?

Answer (score 5):

> I want to use authentication web services that is exposed by my legacy client.

You need to implement Liferay's com.liferay.portal.security.auth.Authenticator class to use your own custom authenticator that would call your web services. This can be plugged into Liferay by adding the folliowing to portal-ext.properties: auth.pipeline.pre=[your classpath].

> But I cannot copy those user information in to liferay database.

I believe that if you don't want to store your user data in Liferay you can also use auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false in the portal-ext.properties file. Mind you, I'm trying to do the same right now and I'm not having much luck.

Good luck!

Ray

Comment: Hi Ray,

But how to have our own login page instead of the login page provided by liferay..Reasin is that we may have additional credential for login.

Thanks for your reply. I will try the same..Please reply me when you see success.

Regards
Vishal G

Comment: But the user's email id need to be configured in the Liferay database for the LR authentication to work. But i dont want the users be configured in LR database at all.

Please let me know if you have a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I have created my own authenticator class, and it is called, and I can authenticate correctly, but login still fails unless I use a user in the LF database.  I have set the auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false in the portal-ext.properties file, any other ideas as to how to authenticate without duplicating all of my users in the liferay database?

Comment: According to Neil Griffin (from Liferay) this is not possible. The user needs to be duplicated in Liferay's database as the unique ID created for the user will be used with other Liferay database tables. See http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/116223#_19_message_116230

Answer (score 1):

The information Ray you gave is correct, as a hint here: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System is a good step by step tutorial which I do use for a similar approach.

regards
Johannes