# Liferay - Custom Authentication Web Service. Do not need user info in liferay db

Tags: liferay

I have followed [Custom Authentication Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035932/liferay-custom-authentication-web-service) link to customize authentication.

But Liferay is still checking whether the same user email id is configured in the liferay db or not. If its not, it is saying that authetication failed.

I do not want to keep any user information in the liferay db. Do any one know how to do that?

Regards
Vishal G

Answer (score 2):

Create dummy users for your real users with fake data.  Liferay requires some sort of Liferay user in the database to function correctly.  You can create one dummy user for each real user or one dummy user for all your users depending on your needs.